# javascript code doesnt work when inserted into html geolocation map

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, geolocation

hi guys im building a mobile app where i have to put a map and show user location and show some other places where the user can go but when i insert it into it doesnt work, so this is my working code link http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/1066/ and the map works the maprkers work and geolocation also work but when i http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/1067/ it doesnt work i think its a very small mistake and im sorry for asking u this but can u correct my code im sure its a small thing :/

```
function initialize() {

    var locations = [
        ['<b>Cafee Bellagio</b> <a href="http://google.com">more info</a><br><br>Gothersgade 11<br>1123 København K<br>3314 5472<br><br><img src="https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/644051119/CoffeeReviewLogo-100.jpg"></img><br><a href="http://google.com">Write a review</a> <a href="http://google.com">Get Directions</a>', 55.6911, 12.5939],
        ['<b>Cafee Nzsikvo</b> <a href="http://google.com">more info</a><br><br>Gothersgade 11<br>1123 København K<br>3314 5472<br><br><img src="https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/644051119/CoffeeReviewLogo-100.jpg"></img><br><a href="http://google.com">Write a review</a> <a href="http://google.com">Get Directions</a>', 55.6883, 12.5597],
        ['<b>Cafee Bellagio</b> <a href="http://google.com">more info</a><br><br>Gothersgade 11<br>1123 København K<br>3314 5472<br><br><img src="https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/644051119/CoffeeReviewLogo-100.jpg"></img><br><a href="http://google.com">Write a review</a> <a href="http://google.com">Get Directions</a>', 55.6832, 12.5714],
        ['<b>Cafee Bellagio</b> <a href="http://google.com">more info</a><br><br>Gothersgade 11<br>1123 København K<br>3314 5472<br><br><img src="https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/644051119/CoffeeReviewLogo-100.jpg"></img><br><a href="http://google.com">Write a review</a> <a href="http://google.com">Get Directions</a>', 55.678272, 12.503643,],
        ['<b>Cafee Bellagio</b> <a href="http://google.com">more info</a><br><br>Gothersgade 11<br>1123 København K<br>3314 5472<br><br><img src="https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/644051119/CoffeeReviewLogo-100.jpg"></img><br><a href="http://google.com">Write a review</a> <a href="http://google.com">Get Directions</a>', 55.713207, 12.526474,]
        ];


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,

        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }

    // Check if user support geo-location
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            var geolocpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                map.setCenter(geolocpoint );
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: geolocpoint,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            }
            // Place a marker
            var geolocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: geolocpoint,
                map: map,
                title: 'Your geolocation',
                icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
            });
        });
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



kastelet.openInfoWindowHtml(
    'Hello, <strong>World!</strong>'
);​
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see two problems here :

1. You do not set a center for the map, it is required as per the doc : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map
2. your `#map` div is inside `#page4` which `height` is not correctly set to display a map canvas

   - set the height of `#page4` and the content of `#page4` to `100%` and everything will be ok
   - this would be the equivalent of the `html, body { height: 100% }` definition in Google's SimpleMap example

See here : http://jsfiddle.net/dJYRJ/ (go to the profile tab, which is #page4)

***NB** : You will then need to tweak your CSS a little bit for the map to display correctly*